# Best ubuntu version for my netbook

Tags: 14.04

what is the best ubuntu version for my Asus EEE PC 1201t netbook, and i'am currently using ubuntu 14.04.2 lts.

Memory: 1.7 GB

Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) Neo Processor MV-40

Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780

Comment: Does current Ubuntu version work well? Then just keep it.

Comment: yup but sometimes it causes me lags.

Comment: You can try Xubuntu or Lubuntu 14.04 32-bit. They consume less resources.

Comment: ok i'll try the lubuntu, it looks like windows. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest lubuntu as well.  I used Ubuntu with the 2d desktop option on a similar machine, but that option doesn't exist in 14.

Comment: I think that the best option would be Xubuntu (more functional than Lubuntu and a bit more resource consumption)

Comment: I'm using ubuntu with openbox desktop or occasionally gnome or blackbox. Minimialistic and fast. Just suggesting

Comment: I use xubuntu on an Asus netbook (well, 2 of them..) - works fine.